# Workmanager launching each time at launch without doing anything

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-workmanager

First time using Stackoverflow !

I have an issue with my Workmanager and I'm asking for help:

When I run my app, its executing without switching my switch to ON. It's happening every time when I install (run) my app, my notification appears without doing anything. (it still works when I'm using my switch after launching )

**MyWorker.java**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    private Workmate workmate;
    private String messageBody;


    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        retrievesWorkmateData();
        return Result.success();
    }
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_settings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigureDesign() {

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        configureToolbar();
        spinnerLanguage();


        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        boolean notificationBoolean = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(BOOLEAN, false);

        final OneTimeWorkRequest simpleRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .build();
        UUID workId = simpleRequest.getId();

        if (notificationBoolean) {
            mSwitch.setChecked(true);
        }

        mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (mSwitch.isChecked()) {
                editor.putBoolean(BOOLEAN, true);
                WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(simpleRequest);
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.Alarm_manager_start), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean(BOOLEAN, false);
                WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(workId);
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.Alarm_manager_cancel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            editor.apply();
        });
    }
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

inside `onConfigureDesign` you are creating `OneTimeWorkRequest` an obtain its `UUID workId = simpleRequest.getId()`. this id is used inside `OnCheckedChangeListener` for starting or canceling work for `WorkManager`. consider this scenario: app doesn't have any pending work to do and user navigates to this switch and schedule work with given `UUID`. then user quits app, even kill it, and then got back to app and navigates again to this switch. `onConfigureDesign` is called again, new `OneTimeWorkRequest` is created and it have new `UUID`. this id won't cancel your previously set request, because it had/have another id... still switch is checked, as its checked/unchecked state is basing just on some `boolean` in `SharedPreferences`

solution would be to store in `SharedPreferences` this `UUID` (`String` in fact, use `toString()` and `fromString(str)`) when work is scheduled and remove it from there when canceling or `doWork()` gets called. initial state of switch should be also set basing on presence of this (any) id in shared prefs

welcome on SO :)

Comment: Hello, thanks you ( i'm new to android/java too )  it's even working when i have nothing in my settingsActivity, i think my app is running doWork() when it's starting.

Comment: it may run previous, not canceled and not executed work. `WorkManager` won't fire when app is killed (App switch btn -> swipe for removing from memory)

Comment: So, WorkManager can't be used when app is killed ? ( because it's my next step )

Comment: it may not fire in some cases, sadly... just put "workmanager when app killed" into some search engine ;) you may consider using `AlarmManager` and/or `JobService`/`JobIntentService`